# Alternative proofs:

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have worked about a result and want to know if there are better ways of proving the following:

$$N^M - (N-1)^M$$
$$=\binom{N}{1}(N-1)^{M-1} + \binom{N}{2} (N-1)^{M-2} + \binom{N}{3} (N-1)^{M-3} + \cdots
+\binom{N}{M}(N-1)^{M-M}.$$

Comment: If M=1, this says that N−(N−1)=N. Should you have (M,C,1) instead of (N,C,1)?

Comment: Yes.  You are right.  It should (M,C,k) in stead of (N,C,k).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expansion of $N^M=((N-1)+1)^M$, if you adjust the $(N,C,k)$ to $(M,C,k)$

Answer (score 1):

We give a combinatorial interpretation, with the $\binom{N}{k}$ replaced by the correct $\binom{M}{k}$.

We have $N$ kids, one of whom is George, and $M$ **distinct** presents. We want to count, in two different ways,  the number of ways to give out the presents, with George getting at least $1$ present.

**Way $1$:** There are $N^M$ ways to distribute the presents. There are $(N-1)^M$ ways to distribute the presents among the $N-1$ non-Georges. So there are $N^M-(N-1)^M$ ways to not shut George out.

**Way $2$:** George may get anywhere from $1$ to $M$ presents. We count the number of ways to distribute the presents so Geoge gets $k$. The $k$ presents George gets can be chosen in $\binom{M}{k}$ ways. For each such way, the remaining $M-k$ presents can be distributed among the remaining kids in $(N-1)^{M-k}$ ways. So there are $\binom{M}{k}(N-1)^{M-k}$ ways to distribute the presents so George gets $k$. Now sum from $k=1$ to $k=M$.

Comment: Can some one tell me how to write the math symbols here?  I know how to write math equations in Microsoft Word but not here.

Comment: I have arrived at the result using similar arguments but not exactly the same.  N^M is the number of you can form M-long words with N symbols and repetitions allowed.  It should equal the sum of number of M-long words without a particular symbol say the first symbol, then the number of M-long words with the first symbol exactly once, the the number of M-long words with the first symbol appearing twice, the number of words with the symbol appearing 3 times so on.

Comment: The combinatorial interpretation I wrote is then not at all new to you. What you had found is mathematically the same as my answer, the "story" just has different characters.